# Can you increase your energy above maximum?

Tags: slay-the-spire

If I have a card that gives me additional energy like Ironclads [Seeing Red](http://slay-the-spire.wikia.com/wiki/Seeing_Red), can I use it while already at maximum energy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using cards like the Ironclads [Seeing Red](http://slay-the-spire.wikia.com/wiki/Seeing_Red) will allow you to increase your energy above your maximum. Combined with Ironclads [Whirlwind](http://slay-the-spire.wikia.com/wiki/Whirlwind) this can be a very lethal combination.

You will have to use all your energy this turn as it'll be reset to your maximum at the beginning of your next turn.

Comment: If you couldn't go above your maximum energy, cards like Flying Knee would be useless: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/slay-the-spire/images/8/82/R_flying-knee.png/revision/latest?cb=20171214115920

Comment: Yeah, this question popped up on my first run after facing only a few enemies. At the time I wasn't sure if you'd have to increase your maximum to get the effect of cards like that. The energy is shown like 3/3, which could read like 3 out of 3, but in fact it should be read as 3 current energy, +3 energy per turn.

Comment: Just a side note - there is a relic now that allows you to retain your unused energy and roll it over to your next turn. You don’t always have to “use it or lose it”.